# Server bandwidth usage with rtmp streaming of video

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-computing, flash, video-streaming

Quick question - I am streaming video from Cloudfront using RTMP streaming via an SWF-based flash player on my EC2 instance. With this setup will I see I/O data from the EC2 instance on account of the streaming via the flash player on the server?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Farseeker - thanks for the note. The videos are in The SWF is the video player. The video it plays are being delivered from C/F. Does that mean essentially that the SWF is as you say 'simply hosted'?

Answer (score 0):

You will see traffic from the following locations:

`Client -> RTMP Server`
`RTMP Server -> Content Location`

If your RTMP Server and the content location are on the same machine, then obviously you won't actually "see" that data.

I'm not 100% sure I understand your setup based on what you've written. Is your SWF hosted on your EC2 instance, or is it actually playing *on* your EC2 instance (on the console, or a service)?

If the SWF is playing ON your EC2 instance, then you'll see the traffic on there, yes, of course.

However, if the SWF is simply HOSTED on your EC2 instance, but the SWF connects directly to Cloudfront, then you will not see any traffic from Cloudfront -> EC2 as RTMP streaming is a client-side activity.